# SoundCloud JS SDK get handler not executing

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

Using the basic examples for the SoundCloud JS SDK, i cannot get a GET requeset to execute the function handler. Using Firebug I can see that request succeeds with appropriate data returned however no matter what I try the handler does not get executed.

```
<script src="//connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js"></script>
<script>
SC.initialize(
{
    client_id: "< my real client id >"
} );

SC.get("/tracks/112798152", function(sound)
{
    console.log( 'finished' );
} );
</script>
```

I've tried this developing locally and live on my website to no avail. Nothing in my hours of searching has shed any light. I'm no noob but it shouldn't be this difficult. Something seems very wrong.

I should note that SC.stream is working properly like so:

```
SC.stream("/tracks/112798152", function(sound)
{
    sound.play();
    console.log('playin');
});
```

I've tried various browsers, updating jQuery and hours of searching. nothing nothing nothing. Very surprised no one else seems to have this problem!

Comment: Your code works for me – http://jsbin.com/AsOdAqiK/1/edit

Comment: perhaps they require the latest version of jQuery - something that should be well documented!

Comment: There's no jQuery included in the jsbin, it's just the SDK that is referenced.

Answer (score 0):

i discovered that the reason for all this is because you can't have the chrome JS debugger open when using the SoundCloud JS API. the calls simply fail. the only debugger that works right through while open is Firefox's debugger (on mac). keep this in mind when using console.log statements to debug your SoundCloud API calls.